# Configure Glassfish to enable CORS

Tags: ajax, glassfish, cross-domain, cors

After searching I dd not find anything about glassfish3.1 and CORS

Is it possible to [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) like on Apache2

I need that for 'same domain' ajax request, from an apache server to query glassfish on its 8080 port, I could use an intermediate php script, but it seems to slow down everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like NO: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16049.

In this bug take a look at fix version which is 4.0 - the next one in product line.

Use any other conventional methods you have. For example, configure Apache mode_rewrite to respond to HTTP Options verb.

Best